Layout service response contains standard values instead of expected rendering data
I have an issue where my layout service will intermittently return standard values such as $name. There are a number of complicating factors such as load balancers, CDN, multiple content delivery servers, geo redundancy, etc. For those reasons I am unable to reliably reproduce the issue, and so far I haven't spotted any obvious clues in the logs.
This issue has been ongoing both before and after a Sitecore 9 to 10 upgrade; however, it seems to be more frequent since upgrading to 10. The layout service endpoint is for a page that is composed of JSON renderings which are server side rendered (no SSG or ISR).
What could cause this to happen? Some ideas are:

Potential Sitecore bug
Transient indexing replication issue
Transient database replication issue
Caching in conjunction with one of the above

UPDATE:
Since posting this question, I was able to reduce but not eliminate the number of events by adding a check in the request pipeline which detects when an item / version is missing, and if so, clear the item cache, and attempt to get the item from the database again. This doesn't fix the issue immediately (the item will still come back as null), but it does appear to fix it after a short bit of time has passed.

is it Sitecore SXA?

It is not Sitecore SXA.
